# How to use updateStateByKey to perform aggregations?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a **DStream[String,(Double,Double)]** to which I am trying to obtain running totals based on the **key:String** by using **updateStateByKey**, but am unable to figure out how to do so, can anyone help me in cracking this. The following is a gist of my code,

```
val updateFunc = (values: Seq[(Double,Double)], state: Option[(Double,Double,Double,Double)]) => {
    val values1 = values.map(x => x._1)
    val values2 = values.map(x => x._2)
    val currentCost = values1.foldLeft(0d)(_+_)
    val currentQuantity = values2.foldLeft(0d)(_+_)
    val currentTotal = {
                          if(currentCost != 0d && currentQuantity != 0d)
                               currentCost * currentQuantity
                          else
                               0d
    }
    val oldTotals = state.getOrElse(0d,0d,0d,0d) //(cost,quantity,total,runningTotal)
    val runningTotal = oldTotals._4+currentTotal
    values.drop(1)
    Some(currentCost,currentQuantity,currentTotal,runningTotal)
}



val dstream: [String,(Double,Double)] = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,zkQuorum,group,topicMap)
                     .window(Seconds(1), Seconds(1))
                     .map(_._2)
                     .map(x => (compact(parse(x,false) \\ "Name").toString(),
                                 (compact(parse(x,false) \\ "Cost").replace('$', ' ').replace('\"',' ').trim.toDouble,
                                  compact(parse(x,false) \\ "quantity").toDouble))
                          )
val result = dstream.updateStateByKey(updateFunc)
result.print()
```

To explain better, In continuation to the code, for the multiple windows of DStream's, I need output like the following,

1st window -> [(a,2,1)(b,2,4)(c,5,1)(d,2,6)(e,4,3)]

output ->

```
       a,2,1,2,2

       b,2,4,8,8

       c,5,1,5,5

       d,2,6,12,12

       e,4,3,12,12
```

2nd window -> [(a,3,4)(b,5,2)(c,6,1)(d,3,6)]

output

```
       a,3,4,12,14

       b,5,2,10,18

       c,6,1,6,11

       d,3,6,18,30
```

3rd window -> [(b,6,6)(e,2,3)]

output

```
       b,6,6,36,54

       e,2,3,6,18
```

I have been trying to make it work but some how I end up getting weird values like 0's in the first three columns of the output at times, or the same key-value pair being used again to update the running total.

I am new to Spark Streaming, so could anyone please help me figuring out on how to get the logic right for the above output?

P.s: I apologize for my way of explanation.

Comment: at glance your update function looks alright - there is possibility that issue is in previous transformations. You can test your update function with unit tests and/or `ConstantInputDStream` (you can create single RDD and stream it constantly - it really helps to test) to confirm whether the issue is in updateStateByKey, previous transformations or data that you receive from Kafka

Comment: @AlexLarikov Thanks for your response mate. I would try unit testing my code now.  How would you tackle my use case using updateStateByKey, just curious? Is spark streaming good for my use case?

Comment: Whether this approach suitable or not - more depends on the your use case, if you can provide more details of what you're trying to achieve (more high level details) - it might be easier to answer that. In general Spark Streaming is capable to handle streaming aggregations and there are multiple approaches that you can take - window computations, updateStateByKey, external state. I was covering some details on those in this answer - this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630251/spark-streaming-stateless-overalpping-windows-vs-keeping-state/34722265#34722265

Comment: @AlexLarikov I am trying to do some computations on the data I get, typically accumulations/aggregations. So I trying to have a <Key,Value> store in which I can save the running totals from the beginning of streaming. But I am not really sure how to do it as I tried it on a simple word count program for a stream and I get accumulated results over the windows, for example, window1[(a,1)(b,1)(c,1)] window2[(a,1)(b,1)(c,1)] window3[(a,1)(b,1)(c,1)] I would end up with the output [(a,6)(b,6)(c,6)] instead of [(a,3)(b,3)(c,3)]. To my guess it is adding like "1+2+3=6" instead of "1+1+1=3".

Comment: @AlexLarikov, thanks for your recent answers, I figured out that spark is not of use for my use case through my research on line and Storm is a best fit as it processes at a record level unlike batches in spark.